# Ansible, ec2_remote_facts - The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible

I have some Ansible playbook

```
---

- name: Sandbox
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: true
  tasks:

   - name: Get facts by filter
     ec2_remote_facts:
       region: "{{ aws_default_region }}"
       filters:
         instance-state-name: running
     register: ec2_remote_facts

   - name: debug
     debug: var=ec2_remote_facts

   - name: Add running sandbox instances to in-memory inventory host group
     add_host:
       hostname: "{{ item.public_ip }}"
       groups: running
     with_items: "{{ ec2_remote_facts.instances }}"

- name: Configure provisioned servers
  hosts: running
  gather_facts: true
  user: ec2-user
  become: true
  roles:
    - base
```

When I run this playbook, I am getting next error:

```
TASK [Add running sandbox instances to in-memory inventory host group] *********
fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "the field 'args' has an invalid value, which appears to include a variable that is undefined. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'public_ip'
```

I am a little confused, because the same code works fine during ec2 creation and provisioning.

In the first play `debug: var=ec2_remote_facts` shows me my instances, which I created during second playbook.

```
---

- name: Sandbox instances
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

   - name: Launch a sandbox instance
     ec2:
       keypair: "{{ aws_default_keypair }}"
       aws_access_key: "{{ aws_access_key }}"
       aws_secret_key: "{{ aws_secret_key }}"
       instance_type: "{{ aws_default_instance_type }}"
       image: "{{ aws_default_ami_image }}"
       region: "{{ aws_default_region }}"
       group: "{{ aws_default_security_group_name }}"
       count: "{{ aws_default_count_of_instances }}"
       instance_tags:
         Name: "{{ aws_default_instance_tag_name }}"
         Group: "{{ aws_default_instance_tag_group }}"
       wait: yes
     register: ec2

   - name: debug
     debug: var=ec2

   - name: Add new sandbox instances to in-memory inventory host group
     add_host:
       hostname: "{{ item.public_ip }}"
       groupname: running
     with_items: "{{ ec2.instances }}"

   - name: Wait for SSH to come up
     wait_for:
       host: "{{ item.public_dns_name }}"
       port: 22
       delay: 60
       timeout: 320
       state: started
     with_items: "{{ ec2.instances }}"

- name: Configure provisioned servers
  hosts: running
  gather_facts: false
  user: ec2-user
  become: true
  roles:
    - base
```

Ansible version is 2.2.1.0

What am I missing? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you get an error on `debug: var=ec2` in the first play? Instead, what is the output of `debug: var=ec2_remote_facts`?

Comment: 'debug: var=ec2_remote_facts' shows me my existing instances

Comment: I did not ask for your explanation. I asked you to include the output in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Beware of inconsistency in results of `ec2` and `ec2_remote_facts`.

`ec2` populates `private_ip` and `public_ip`.
`ec2_remote_facts` populates `private_ip_address` and `public_ip_address`.

Change your `add_host` task appropriately for each case.